# Docmd.TransferText question

Tags: ms-access, macros, vba

b'h

i will be programmatically importing a text file into a table. i have saved the import steps. i will use this:

```
DoCmd.TransferText(TransferType, SpecificationName, TableName, FileName, HasFieldNames, HTMLTableName, CodePage)
```

to do the import.

this is what `SpecificationName` means:

Specification Name The specification name for the set of options that determines how a text file is imported, exported, or linked. For a fixed-width text file, you must either specify a specification name or use a schema.ini file, which should be stored in the same directory as the imported, linked, or exported text file.

i do need a specific specification; however i do not know how to specify one. when i manually imported a table, i did save the specifications for my import, however i do not know how to call this in the `TransferText`.

does anyone know how to specify `SpecificationName` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do the import manually, you can save the import options as a specification.  You assign a name to the specification at the time you create it.  In Access 2003, click the *Advanced* button on the *Import Text Wizard*.  Then you will get a dialog for <*filename> Import Specification*; click the *Save As* button and assign a *Specification Name* ... for example "MySpec".

Use that name (in quotes) as the *SpecificationName* option for your *DoCmd.TransferText* command.

Comment: I would have to start up a machine with 2007 to check.  I can do that if you can't find anything similar to my description for 2003.  Let me know.