# DoCmd.TransferText with non-US regional settings

Tags: ms-access, vba

My client has a Windows regional settings that has comma as a decimal place separator and semicolon as a list separator, which is a typical format settings for most European countries. When my code tries to run `DoCmd.TransferText` without export specification, it throws this error: [image]

So my solution would be to use export specification as adviced here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Well, as I found (for example here: [Docmd.TransferText question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986456/docmd-transfertext-question)) the only way to create the user specification is to manually run some Export wizard. In it I can set which decimal place separator and which list separator I want to use. Looks good, but there is a problem: the export specification also contains information about the exported columns and their formats. But I am creating my export query dynamically, the columns are different for each export run. How can I use the export specification? Or is there any other solution to my problem?

Note: Of course, I cannot force my client to change his Windows regional settings. Neither can I export the CSV files just writing value by value to raw text file output in VBA because the queries are large and this would probably take hours to finish. I do not mind if the final CSV files have commas as list separators and points as decimal separators (US format) or semicolons as list separators and commas as decimal separators (local format settings) - I do not care because I can tweak the further steps in the processing of the CSVs accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices: (a) use the inline-text version of the export format specification, or (b) create an export specification using the wizard, then use normal Access database methods to modify the values in the export specification table.